# Excel - Refresh All duplicate pivot table propertis

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, excel-365

Good day,
the Refresh All function in Excel does not work properly for me.

"Properties in Report" and "Properties in Tooltips" are duplicated.

Procedure:
After adding a pivot table and adding attributes, everything looks correct, and Refresh All also behaves correctly. After saving, reopening and then Refresh All, "Properties in Report" and "Properties in Tooltips" are duplicated.

When selecting propertis, the excel application will fail.

I identified the Refresh All function as the source of this problem. Similar behavior did not occur in previous versions of Excel.

I encountered this problem in Excel 365 x64.

Unfortunately, for some reason, the problem does not arise on some Excel, it probably has something to do with managing Microsoft accounts.

Please, has anyone seen it?
Has anyone been able to solve the problem?

Comment: Try refreshing the `PivotCache`, too. A piece of code will not look well here. I will try an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next approach, please:

```
Sub testRefreshAll()
 Dim pCs as PivotCache

 ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll 

 For each pCs in ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
     pCs Refresh
 Next pc
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to run it. And unfortunately with the same result. Again, the data duplicated about 4 times. Interestingly, a simple Refresh is fine.